# Is the stereographic projection a homomorphism between the sphere and the plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, stereographic-projections

I am taking a course on complex analysis, and we define the stereographic projection. Isn't this an onto and $1-1$ continuous mapping from the sphere to the plane ? Meaning that it exist a homomorphism between the sphere and the plane ? But if I remember correctly in differential geometry we said that such homomorphism cant exist. At least I know for a fact that they have different Gauss curvature.

Comment: I think you mean *homeomorphism*. Homeomorphisms are a topological notion, so they need not preserve curvature. I think what you're saying is that there can be no isometry between the sphere and the plane. Also note that stereographic projection is only defined on the sphere minus a point: it's not defined at the "north pole".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The sphere is compact,  and the plane isn't,  so there can be no such homeomorphism.

Stereographic projection is a homeomorphism between the sphere minus a point and the plane.